# How to convert date ICT to UTC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, react-datepicker

I had problem with UTC time . I have a date

> Thu Nov 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)

And now want to convert to

> 23 Nov 2017 17:00:00 GMT

But result is after convert is

> 22 Nov 2017 17:00:00 GMT

This is my code:

```
 let myDate = new Date(v.date);
 /// myDate = **Thu Nov 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)**;
 let myDateConvert = myDate.toUTCString();
 /// myDateConvert = **22 Nov 2017 17:00:00 GMT**;
```

I use react-datepicker and momentjs

[image]

Thanks all with any helping

Comment: `2017-11-23 00:00:00 +07:00` is `2017-11-22 17:00:00 +00:00`, why you are expecting `Nov 23`?

Comment: I'm using momentjs and i need to get correct date is 2017-11-23 to push to server API. If i dont convert date to UTC , my server would lost a day .

Comment: There is no momentjs in your code sample, anyway even if you use momentjs `2017-11-23 00:00:00 +07:00` will always be converted into `2017-11-22 17:00:00 +00:00`, see [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20171122T170000&p1=tz_ict&p2=1440).

Comment: @VincenzoC , i added more image when i selected a day in react-datepicker. I only convert from ITC to UTC, my location in Viet Nam

Comment: @ThucHồ Both are same , store the date in utc format, while retrieving from server convert to local time again.

Comment: Thanks @Durga, I'll try

Comment: I saw and resolved problem. I just need to add more my country hour UTC (+7) before send to server .  Thank @VincenzoC and Durga once again


`let offset = moment().utcOffset() / 60;
  let myStringDate = date.toISOString();
  return moment(new Date(new Date(myStringDate).getTime() + 60 * 60 * offset * 1000)).utc();`